# Python API for USDA nutritional facts

Tags: python, pandas, usda-fooddata-central-api

I am using an API that retrieves all the nutritional facts about fruits from the USDA, and posts them on an Excel sheet, but I only get 50 results. I want to export every fruit from their web site. How do I get the whole list?

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

def call_API(foodName, apiKey):
    url = f'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key={apiKey}&query={foodName}'
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()
    
api_response = call_API('raw', '#API KEY')

# search
table_data = []
for food_item in api_response['foods']:
    row = {
        "Description": food_item["description"]
        }

    for nutrient in food_item["foodNutrients"]:
        nutrient_name = nutrient["nutrientName"]
        row[nutrient_name] = nutrient["value"]
    table_data.append(row)

# creating a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
print(df.iloc[-1])

df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always check the [API documentation](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/fdcnal/food-data_central_api/1.0.1#/FDC/getFoodsSearch) you are using. If you open in your browser or print the `api_response` from your request, you'll see there are keys in the response that say `currentPage` and `totalPages`, which means results are paged and you'll have to iterate over those pages to get all the foods from your search criteria.

In the documentation, one of the parameters is `pageSize` which default is 50 but the maximum can be set to 200 and to set the page number you can use the parameter `pageNumber`.

So you'll have to do something like this.

```py
def call_API(foodName, apiKey):
    foods = []
    url = f"https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key={apiKey}&query={foodName}&PageSize=200"
    with requests.Session() as req:
        try:
            r = req.get(url, timeout=10)
            r.raise_for_status()
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
            print(f"Error: {err}")
            return None
        api_response = r.json()
        foods.extend(api_response["foods"])
        for page in range(2, api_response["totalPages"] + 1):
            try:
                r = req.get(url + f"&pageNumber={page}", timeout=10)
                r.raise_for_status()
            except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
                print(f"Error: {err}")
                break
            api_response = r.json()
            foods.extend(api_response["foods"])
    return foods

food_items = call_API("raw", "API_KEY")

for food_item in food_items:
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pageNumber as shown below:

```
https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=your_key&query=raw&pageNumber=2
```

If you want to pull page count before looping try:

```
pages = pd.json_normalize(data=api_response).totalPages.squeeze()
```

Answer (score 0):

using panda's module you could try the following changes:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

def call_API(foodName, apiKey):
    url = f'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key={apiKey}&query={foodName}'
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        r.raise_for_status()  # Raise an HTTPError for bad requests
        return r.json()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error during API call: {e}")
        return None

def main():
    apiKey = 'coIkTLZKgHh6Ta2m8O7yAbZhx6c5JdICjtHdAW7h'
    foodName = 'raw'  # Replace with the desired food item

    api_response = call_API(foodName, apiKey)

    if api_response:
        table_data = []

        for food_item in api_response['foods']:
            row = {"Description": food_item["description"]}
    
            for nutrient in food_item["foodNutrients"]:
                nutrient_name = nutrient["nutrientName"]
                row[nutrient_name] = nutrient["value"]
            
            table_data.append(row)

        df = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
        print(df.iloc[-1])

        # Save DataFrame to Excel file
        df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
        print("Data saved to 'output.xlsx'.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).